# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable- Sorry if AP

Tags: python, self

```
class Car:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mpg):
        # instance variables
        self.carMake = make
        self.carModel=model
        self.carYear = year
        self.efficiency=mpg
        self.gas = 0

    # special method
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s"%(self.carYear, self.carMake, self.carModel)

    def refuel(self,gallon):
        if gallon < 0:
            print("Sorry, amount cannot be negative")
        else:
            self.gas=self.gas+gallon
            print (self.gas)
            print("Added %.2f gallon of gas to the tank"%(self.gas))

    def gas(self):
        print(self.gas)


> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in
> <module>
>     c1.gas() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `gas` and your instance attribute `gas` created in `__init__` have the same name. The method is stored on the class, but is "shadowed" by the attribute stored on the instance, since Python first looks for names on the instance, then on the class and its parents.

So `self.gas` is an integer and you can't call it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `self.gas` initialized to an `int` in the `__init__()` method, but then you define a method named `gas()` as well. Once `__init__()` runs, `self.gas` is an `int`. I'm guessing somewhere you are calling `gas()` on an instance of this class.

Rename your `gas()` method to something like `print_gas()`, or, wherever you're calling this, instead of doing `c1.gas()`, just do `print c1.gas`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this class Test in a file called test.py:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=3
    def x(self):
        print self.x
```

Now I import class Test in my console and see what methods it has:

```
>>> from test import Test
>>> [method for method in dir(Test) if callable(getattr(Test, method))]
['__init__', 'x']
```

Notice that it has the method x. Now let's create an instance of Test

```
>>> k=Test()
```

Let's see what methods we have

```
>>> [method for method in dir(k) if callable(getattr(k, method))]
['__init__']
>>>
```

As you can see the method x is no longer available. why?

When you created k as an instance of Test, it executes the `__init__` method and sees `self.x=3` which redefines x to be just a variable in `self` and your method `x()` is gone. So when you do `k.x()` it thinks that you are doing it on `self.x` that you set in `__init__` which is not callable. However just `k.x` will work as I show below:

```
>>> k.x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> k.x
3
>>>
```

The conclusion is don't name your variables and methods the same.